Find the volume of the solid inside the cylinder $x^2+y^2-2ay=0$ and between $z=0$ and the paraboloid $4az=x^2+y^2$ equals $\frac{3\pi a^3}{8}.$
Find the volume of the solid inside the cylinder $x^2+y^2-2ay=0$ and between $z=0$ and the paraboloid $4az=x^2+y^2$ equals $\frac{3\pi a^3}{8}.$
I tried solving this problem as follows:
The equation of the cylinder is $x^2+(y-a)^2=a^2.$ So, the region $E$ as given in the problem is $$E=\{(x,y,z):(x,y)\in D\space \text{and } 0\leq z\leq (x^2+y^2)/(4a)\}$$ where $D$ is a disk of radius $a$ centered at $(0,a)$ in the $xy$ plane. So, the volume of the region $E$ will be $$V={\int\int\int}_E dV={\int\int}_{D}\int_{0}^{\frac{x^2+y^2}{4a}}dzdA=\int_{-a}^{a}\int_{a-\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}^{a+\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}\frac{x^2+y^2}{4a}dydx.$$
So, we need to evaluate the above integral. This means, $V=\int_{-a}^{a}\int_{a-\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}^{a+\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}\frac{x^2+y^2}{4a}dydx=\\\int_{-a}^a\frac{[3x^2[a+\sqrt{a^2-x^2}-a+\sqrt{a^2-x^2}]+(a+\sqrt{a^2-x^2})^3-(a-\sqrt{a^2-x^2})^3]}{12a}dx$

This becomes a very complicated integral. I don't know how to use polar coordinates to solve this as I learnt to use it only when we have a circle centered at the origin but $D$ is not centered at the origin. Any help regarding hhis issue will be greatly appreciated.
